# Почему AlarmManager не работает?

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver, уведомления

Ребята, AlarmManager не срабатывает на Android P. Кто сталкивался с проблемой? Я понять не могу почему? BroadcastReceiver зарегистрирован в манифесте. В AlarmReceiver просто NotificationManager с методом showNotification, который формирует само уведомление. (Забегая немного вперед в ожидании вопроса про Notification Channels, я предусмотрел изменения в коде уведомлений и добавил поддержку каналов для работы на более новых версиях Android.)

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.apply { timeInMillis = launch.timestamp * 1000 }
    val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    alarmIntent.action = "NOTIFICATION_ACTION"
    alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_NAME, launch.title)
    alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_DETAIL, "Is launching right now!")
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        alarmIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Right before set at: ${formatDate(calendar.timeInMillis)}")
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    }
```

Comment: Работает на других версиях этот код?

Comment: Работает на более старых версиях.

Comment: А в логах приходит в AlarmReceiver?

Comment: нет вообще не срабатывает, я же говорю

Comment: код рабочий, есть ограничения по частоте вызовов, например если вы поставите через 5 минут ничего не сработает

Comment: Вообще странно, в доках [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) пишут, что система может запустить этот алярм когда ей приспичит, несмотря на все эти `exact` и `allow`. Попробуйте вот эту функцию [setAlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). Вроде бы у меня в будильнике она работала корректно на последних аднроидах.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать